# Qt app pairing with bluetooth printer - passing PIN to printer

Tags: qt, printing, bluetooth

I have following code, header file:
**uebluetoothmanager.h**:

```
#ifndef UEBLUETOOTHMANAGER_H
#define UEBLUETOOTHMANAGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QBluetoothServiceInfo>
#include <QBluetoothLocalDevice>
#include <QDebug>

#include "../settings/uedefaults.h"

class UeBluetoothManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent* m_ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent;
    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent* m_ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent;
    QBluetoothLocalDevice* m_ueBtPrinter;

public:
    explicit UeBluetoothManager(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~UeBluetoothManager();

    inline void ueSetBtServiceDiscoveryAgent(QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent* const btServiceDiscoveryAgent)
        { this->m_ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent=btServiceDiscoveryAgent; }
    inline void ueSetBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent(QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent* const btDeviceDiscoveryAgent)
        { this->m_ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent=btDeviceDiscoveryAgent; }
    inline void ueSetBtPrinter(QBluetoothLocalDevice* btLocalDevice)
        { this->m_ueBtPrinter=btLocalDevice; }

    inline QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent* ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent() const
        { return this->m_ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent; }
    inline QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent* ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent() const
        { return this->m_ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent; }
    inline QBluetoothLocalDevice* ueBtPrinter() const
        { return this->m_ueBtPrinter; }

signals:

public slots:
    void ueSlotServiceDiscovered(const QBluetoothServiceInfo&);
    void ueSlotDeviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo& deviceInfo);
    void ueSlotPairingFinished(const QBluetoothAddress& address,
                               QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing);
};

#endif // UEBLUETOOTHMANAGER_H
```

and its implementation, **uebluetoothmanager.cpp**:

```
#include "uebluetoothmanager.h"

UeBluetoothManager::UeBluetoothManager(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->ueSetBtServiceDiscoveryAgent(new QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent(this));
    this->ueSetBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent(new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this));
    this->ueSetBtPrinter(new QBluetoothLocalDevice(this));

    this->connect(this->ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent(),
                  SIGNAL(serviceDiscovered(QBluetoothServiceInfo)),
                  this,
                  SLOT(ueSlotServiceDiscovered(QBluetoothServiceInfo)));

    this->connect(this->ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent(),
                  SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)),
                  this,
                  SLOT(ueSlotDeviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)));

    this->connect(this->ueBtPrinter(),
                  SIGNAL(pairingFinished(QBluetoothAddress,
                                         QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing)),
                  this,
                  SLOT(ueSlotPairingFinished(QBluetoothAddress,
                                             QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing)));

    this->ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent()->start();
    this->ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent()->start();
}   // default constructor

UeBluetoothManager::~UeBluetoothManager()
{
    delete this->ueBtPrinter();
    delete this->ueBtDeviceDiscoveryAgent();
    delete this->ueBtServiceDiscoveryAgent();
}   // destructor

void UeBluetoothManager::ueSlotServiceDiscovered(const QBluetoothServiceInfo& info)
{
    qDebug() << info.serviceName()
             << " "
             << info.serviceDescription()
             << " "
             << info.serviceProvider();
}   // ueSlotServiceDiscovered

void UeBluetoothManager::ueSlotDeviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo& info)
{
    QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing pairingStatus=this->ueBtPrinter()->pairingStatus(info.address());

    if(info.name().contains(UeHardware::UeReceiptPrinter::UeReceiptPrinterTSM210::PRINTER_NAME,
                            Qt::CaseSensitive))
    {
//        if(pairingStatus==QBluetoothLocalDevice::Unpaired)
//        {
            this->ueBtPrinter()->requestPairing(info.address(),
                                                QBluetoothLocalDevice::AuthorizedPaired);
//        }   // if
    }   // if
}   // ueSlotDeviceDiscovered

void UeBluetoothManager::ueSlotPairingFinished(const QBluetoothAddress& address,
                                               QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing pairing)
{
    qDebug() << "Pairing with "
             << address.toString()
             << " finished with status "
             << pairing
             << ".";
}   // ueSlotPairingFinished
```

Now, the purpose of this code (I am using `KUbuntu 15.04` kernel `Linux work002 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `Qt 5.5.0`) is to establish paired connection with bluetooth POS receipt printer. Printer has default PIN valued `1234`. How do I send this pin number using [Qt Bluetooth API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html) to printer so the app gets paired with it (inside public slot `ueSlotDeviceDiscovered`)? The device and its service gets discovered (`qDebug` outputs):

> Pairing with  "20:13:08:12:07:02"  finished with status <<  1 .
>
> "Dev B"   ""   ""

From the printer docs, the *blue led diode* turns on once printer is successfully paired with device but after this code executes this diode is not active. In current code, I have a line

```
this->ueBtPrinter()->requestPairing(info.address(),QBluetoothLocalDevice::Paired);
```

instead of

```
this->ueBtPrinter()>requestPairing(info.address(),QBluetoothLocalDevice::AuthorizedPaired);
```

because if the upper line is active, I get `qDebug()` output from slots, if `QBluetoothLocalDevice::AuthorizedPaired` is active, I do not get `qDebug()` output at all, but I should/must use `QBluetoothLocalDevice::AuthorizedPaired` to get that *blue led* turned on. How do I pass pin code to printer in `QBluetoothLocalDevice::AuthorizedPaired` mode? And this `Dev B` service of printer seems to be its simaluted serial port, so how do I open this port, maybe using [QSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html)?
**One important info: This app is being developed in Linux, but will be deployed to Android tablet!**

Comment: are you using Linux?

Comment: @ramtheconqueror I've added more info to topic and yes I am using linux.

Comment: I'm sorry, you won't be happy to hear this, BUT, `Qt` has no built in support for supplying custom PIN during authorisation. You have to use `QDBus` module and define your own classes (a couple) to add this functionality. Let me know if you are struck, I will dig some bookmarks I've collected.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror hmm, the point is the app is being developed in Linux in Qt, but it will be deplyed to Android Tablet, as I added in question. What about if I dispose whole `QtBluetooth` module and work directly with CUPS library and add printer on os level in target device (Android+CUPS)?